# WMI query to check setting "Reversible Encryption" in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, group-policy, wmi, password-policy

In Windows XP, there are two settings in Group Policy I'm looking at:

- Password must meet complexity requirements
- Store password using reversible encryption

Both of these settings are under Local Computer Policy/Computer Config/Windows Settings/Security Settings/Account Policies/Password Policy.

For the first one, I have found the setting in RSOP_SecuritySettingBoolean class in WMI. However, I can't find the latter. Does anybody know in which class in WMI can I read that particular setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revisiting MSDN's labyrinth, I chanced upon this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms813423.aspx

> Storing passwords using reversible encryption is essentially the same as storing clear-text versions of the passwords.

Apparently, the answer has been staring at me in the face for a long time already. It is the same class, but the KeyName is "ClearTextPassword".

Answer (score 0):

Would the other class you are looking for be Class RSOP_SecurityEventLogSettingNumeric?

Comment: I have put in the wrong WMI class above; it should have been RSOP_SecuritySettingBoolean. I have looked at RSOP_SecuritySettingNumeric as well, but with no luck. Apparently, the setting is also in the same class.